Insertar la información de un excel con datos masivo a una tabla en sqlserver
Necesito insertar un excel com 41000 filas y 86 columnas a una tabla sql, la extensión de la entrada del archivo tiene que ser xlsx, e probado transformarlo pero no e podido hacerlo algún consejo o tips que tengan para la transformación de archivos, estoy usando laravel 10 y use laravel excel para intentar hacer la conversión pero no pude
